# Is there a method for keeping the id I set for an asp .net control when it outputs to HTML?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

When I create a form, I try to make accessibility a top priority, but the output from asp .NET negates some of this. For example, when I set a label tag for an input tag, I create it a such:

```
<label for="frmFirstName">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<asp:TextBox id="frmFirstName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
```

But, when the HTML is output from the page, it is output as:

```
<label for="frmFirstName">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input name="ctl00$phMainContent$frmFirstName" type="text" id="ctl00_phMainContent_frmFirstName" class="textbox" />
```

This is a problem, as now the label is no longer tied to the input element. Is there a way to force .NET to output the *exact* id I set for the input field? I shouldn't have to use Javascript to correct something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `asp:Label` element and point its `AssociatedControlId` property to your textbox.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" AssociatedControlId="frmFirstName">First Name<span class="required">*</span></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox id="frmFirstName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
```

That should output the correct HTML for you.

Comment: The "<asp:Label>" creates a "<span>" tag, which is incorrect. It needs to be a "<label>" tag for proper accessibility.

Comment: Normally, `Label` emits `span`, but if you add the `AssociatedControlID` property, it renders a `label` element in the HTML.

Comment: Whoa. Well, whaddaya know... Thanks. This helps greatly.

Answer (score 11):

If you use ASP.Net 4 you can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) attribute of the control to `static`. This will let it keep the value of the ID tag when rendered.

Comment: Unfortunately, the CMS our company uses is still set on 2.0, and they don't want to update the server.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the AssociatedControlId and <%= control.ClientId %> solutions, if your control (in this case, "frmFirstName") is guaranteed to be the only control with that ID on the page, then you can set the ClientIDMode property of the control to "Static", which will mean that ASP.NET will not munge the ID in the rendered HTML.

For example:

```
<label for="frmFirstName" runat="server" ID="lblFirstName">First Name</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="frmFirstName" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

will render as

```
<label for="frmFirstName" id="some$aspnet$id$lblFirstName">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="frmFirstName" />
```

This will also make it easier if you happen to need to refer to it from Javascript, since it can be a pain to render ASP.NET's auto IDs in Javascript (as far as I know, it's impossible to do in a seperate .js file, you'd need to embed the JS on the page and use <%= control.ClientID %>).

See more about ClientIDMode here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ClientId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property. This is what will be output as the control Id in HTML and what you can use client side to reference the rendered element:

```
<label for="<%:frmFirstName.ClientId%>">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<asp:TextBox id="frmFirstName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" /
```

Note:

`<%:%>` is new with ASP.NET 4.0 - you will need to use `<%=%>` if on .NET 3.5 and before.

Edit:

Just to add that `ClientId` is the way to go when referencing the control from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks again. This method, though a bit dirty, works for what I need to do.

Comment: @Adam - this is how ASP.NET works and why `ClientID` exists. Yeah, it doesn't look very nice, but that's how it is with webforms. You may want to check out ASP.NET MVC if you want cleaner markup.