# Any idea why this Jquery autocomplete is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, autocomplete

A lot of the questions I've found regarding jquery's autocomplete not working seem to be around having incorrect JSON, but I'm just trying to use the simple example with an array to get it to work. I am able to get it running in a newly created text file, but I need to get it working in a fairly large asp.net application(which I unfortunately took over from another developer, so I didn't set it up).

```
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

});

That is my very simple auto complete code. If I put that in a text file with some html and the required references, it'll work. But then if I put the same thing on a textbox in my asp.net application it does not work. I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the css, because when I put it into the text file and used

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

it wouldn't work. That's the code on jqueryui.com When I changed it to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">`

it did. I'm assuming something is interfering with it...any idea what that could be? There are multiple css sheets already in this application and I'm not quite sure how to tell.

Thanks for any help you can provide. If anyone even has an idea of what I could check, that would be extremely helpful.

EDIT: Here is the actual code I'm using:

```
<div id="Question_5" class="question">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Q51UP">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Q51Label"></asp:Label>
                                <label style="color: #D9534F">* </label>
                                <br />

                                <asp:TextBox ID="Q51TextBox" class="text-box MyStyleSheet" runat="server" Width="200%"></asp:TextBox>

                                    <br />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="false" ID="v5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Q51TextBox"
                                    ErrorMessage="Value Required!" InitialValue="" ForeColor="#d9534f" SetFocusOnError="true">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <div style="height: 0px;"></div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
```

and then in my javascript:

```
var availableTutorials = [
               "ActionScript",
               "Boostrap",
               "C",
               "C++",
            ];
       $("#Q51Textbox").autocomplete({
                source: availableTutorials
       });
```

Comment: I plugged both stylesheets into this fiddle with no issue. Do you have any errors in the console for your ASP.NET application? http://jsfiddle.net/dgautsch/tenjngrd/

Comment: No, it runs fine, it just acts like a regular textbox with no autocomplete attached.

Comment: inspect the textbox in a browser.  I suspect that the actual ID on the client side isn't `Q51Textbox`

Comment: Not sure if you checked.  But here's a question that might help you figure it out http://stackoverflow.com/q/3842639/1385672

Comment: Nice that was it, it's being called MainContent_Q51TextBox. Thanks very much sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Q51TextBox"....
```

and in your js you call the TextBox id with:

`$("#Q51Textbox")` (change the lowercase 'b' in 'box')